# Unable to connect: We could not register this data source for all gateway instances within this cluster.

Tags: db2, powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I have developed some reports using power bi desktop which is using IBM DB2 as datasource. I have installed On-premises data gateway in my power bi system and configured. I have to create ibm db2 datasource connection in power bi web to make live connection with my IBM DB2 database. When i tried to create datasource connection it showing me unable to connect error message.I have given correct credentials but still it showing the same error. Am i missing anything? any special permissions needed to provide from IBM DB2 database admin side? Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance,
Kannas

Comment: Unable to connect: We encountered an error while trying to connect to ataitd01. Details: "We could not register this data source for all gateway instances within this cluster. Please find more details below about specific errors for each gateway instance."Show details
Troubleshoot connection problems".  This is what i am getting when i tried to connect db2 with power bi web.

Comment: Have you verified connectivity between Powerbi-web and your on-premises Gateway? Are all the relevant ports opened and hostnames whitelisted? Have you verified connectivity between your on-premises Gateway and your Db2 database?

Answer (score 5):

I had an identical error. The issue appears to be related to the credentials given in the data source settings when configuring in the online service. In my case I had not entered the domain with the username.

Comment: Thank you very much! your answer helped me a lot. It's frustrating that the error message doesn't say anything about it...

Comment: Hi @Omar - if its useful you may as well flag it as such. Thanks